# NodeJS/Express API real time notification with React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to implement real time notifications. The current code looks something like:

```
exports.doFooBar = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // doing something here
  // ...................
  const onlyAfewUsers = getUsersWhoShouldBeNotified();

  // somehow notify the users that are in "onlyAfewUsers"

  // ... something else

  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    message: "......"
  });
});
```

The frontend is a react webapp that consumes this API. I've looked into socket.io and that seems like something that I can use in my case. But, how do I figure out how to "look"/"poll" for notifications on the React frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please explain a little more about the usecase.

Also tell you need to send the push notifications(Firebase messaging) or basic in app notification in navbar like stackoverflow.

Comment: My usecase is more like the stackoverflow navbar notifications. Keeping in mind this is a web app and not a mobile app. Thankyou

Comment: Ok so I got your use case.
I can help you with doing the notification setup using React and Express.
I can't basically tell what to do exactly with socket.

But can guide to use with firebase realtime.
So if you want I can provide you th code and help you

Comment: Any help would be great! Please let me know

Comment: 1) make a model to store all the notifications of a user.

2) Push a notification to  the model according to the need, (eg someone follows the user).

3) Now to render to the dashborrd/frontend, what you need do is get the notifications for that particular user.

4) Filter them as read and unread.

5) Show the count of Unread notification, and as soon as the user clicks on the notification icon, make request to update status of all the notification to read and set count state to 0.

If using firebase, than the new notification will be seen instantly else on every page refresh .

Comment: If you need the frontend Component and using Material Ui, i can give you the code.

Else for front end just need to do is.
1) On opening menu,show the notifications and mark them as read.

Comment: Thanks, can you also please show some code examples?

Comment: For fronetend the code is present at-
https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-client/blob/master/src/components/layout/Notifications.js

For backend using node and firebase-
https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-functions/blob/2403eea52aece81286602aea47bc88520c95131d/functions/handlers/users.js#L173

For marking notification as read-
https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-functions/blob/2403eea52aece81286602aea47bc88520c95131d/functions/handlers/users.js#L258

This contain all the code.

If you find any problem in implementing this,feel free to ask,